# Image not displaying even with valid src setting?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using MVC (Razor view), and the page I am opening is opened using window.open() with a target of _blank (not sure if this is relevant or not).  On the offending page, a thumbnail is displayed.

The html I am using is:

```
<img src="@ViewBag.thumbnailUrl" />
```

The thumbnailUrl is in the form of https://mysite.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

When I view the source of the page, and I go to the url the src is pointing at, I see the thumbnail I want displayed - however on the page itself, where the thumbnail is SUPPOSED to be displaying, sometimes I have a broken image link, and other times I have a thumbnail.   The intended result, of course, is that it will ALWAYS show a thumbnail.

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: No, it appears to only be happening in Chrome.  I had to double check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's going to change anything but did you try using

```
<img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.thumbnailUrl)" />
```

Where and how did you specify that it had to open in a new window?

Comment: Elodie, that didn't work either.  It appears that it has to do with the speed of the page loading.  On page load, it is initiating a download.  The way the download is initiated is that it redirects itself to a page that returns the file to be downloaded (which the thumbnail depicts).  I am redirecting using javascript - so I wrapped the call to the javascript function in a window.onload() call, and now the image is always showing.  Is there a better way to do this? (I dislike the auto download AND the window.onload() part because it feels hacky).

Comment: So isn't the speed of the page loading the problem and not the thumbnail? It isn't clear for me as I don't see your code and I don't know what you are trying to do in your page.

Comment: As it turns out, it's a symptom of the page load speed.  I initially thought, and was pursuing the track, that there was something else wrong.